# How to start with facebook SDK in android?

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I'm new to android developement in general, but i already got the basic. I want to use the facebook SDK to create an android app, although i have not found a reliable source of information on what methods or classes to use.
I tried to follow the android tutorial on facebook developers, but i am stuck at the step where i am supposed to build and run the project:

```
Step 6.4: Build and run the project
Build and run the 'MyGreatApp' project. This should launch in the same emulator where you install the Facebook.apk. You will be prompted with the user authorization dialog (You may have to login to the Facebook app if not already done so):
```

but the code provided seems to have errors in these lines:

```
facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener(){

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
```

it says: 
-**The method authorize from the type facebook refers to the missing type activity.**

-**The type new Facebook.DialogListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Facebook.DialogListener.onComplete(Bundle)**

```
@Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
```

-**The method onComplete(Bundle) of type new Facebook.DialogListener(){} must override or implement a supertype method**

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

-**The method authorizeCallback(int, int, Intent) from the type Facebook refers to the missing type Intent**